# Swift: Hash value of enum is getting random numbers

Tags: enums, xcode10, swift4.2

I have the following enum:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case One
    case Two
    case Three
}
```

But when I print this line:

```
print("This is the hash value of One \(MyEnum.One.hashValue)")
```

I get the following output:

```
This is the hash value of One -7827947590157343570
```

if I re-run the code I get:

```
This is the hash value of One 7980945707037922449
```

Should I being getting something like this:
 This is the hash value of One 0

My question for you guys why am I getting random numbers?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question it is well documented [hashValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable/1540917-hashvalue)

The short answer is that this is normal behaviour.

> Hash values are not guaranteed to be equal across different executions
>   of your program. Do not save hash values to use during a future
>   execution

Should I being getting something like this?

```
This is the hash value of One 0
```

No. `HashValue` is different from `RawValue`. If you want your enumeration cases to have a rawValue starting at 0 you need to declare your enumeration type as Int. Btw note that it is Swift naming convention to name your enumeration cases starting with a lowercase letter:

```
enum TestEnum: Int {
    case one
    case two
    case three
}
```

---

```
TestEnum.one.rawValue  // 0
TestEnum.two.rawValue  // 1
TestEnum.three.rawValue  // 2
```